# C++ Using memcpy to fill a vector in a struct

Tags: c++, struct, memcpy

I would like to fill a struct using memcpy.

The struct is declared like this:

```
struct udtFeatures
{
    vector<unsigned char>ByteFeatures;
};
```

And this is where I would like fill the bytes:

```
void clsMapping::FeedFeaturesFromMap(udtFeatures &uFeatures,int uOtherIndex)
{
    int iBytePos=this->Content()[uOtherIndex].ByteStart;
    int iByteCount=this->Content()[uOtherIndex].ByteCount;

    memcpy(uFeatures.ByteFeatures, &((char*)(m_pVoiceData))[iBytePos],iByteCount);
}
```

However memcpy does not like this.

The compiler says:

No matching conversion function found for

```
std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char>> in void *.
```

I guess it is because it .ByteFeatures is just a pointer?

How could I do this?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: When programming in C++ (as oposed to C)I would suggest using `std::copy` instead of `memcpy`, since the former actually does the right thing when confronted with non primitive types (and works just as well with primitives)

Comment: An interesting question would be *Why do you want to use `memcpy`?`

Comment: Because I need to copy the bytes from a memory mapped file, and I thought memcpy was the fastest available way to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I guess it is because it .ByteFeatures is just a pointer?

No, it's because it *isn't* just a pointer. It's a vector.

> How could I do this?

If you want a pointer to the array managed by the vector, then that's `uFeatures.ByteFeatures.data()` or `&uFeatures.ByteFeatures[0]`. Alternatively, you might consider using `std::copy` instead.

In either case, make sure the vector is large enough before copying things into it.

Answer (score 0):

It *would* be possible to use `memcpy` to initialize a `std::vector`, but not advisable.

Instead use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
std::copy(&m_pVoiceData[iBytePos], &m_pVoiceData[iBytePos + iByteCount],
          std::back_inserter(uFeatures.ByteFeatures));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant fill `std::vector` using memcpy (Well.. there is a way, but for you is better to think it as if not). Use `std::copy` or fill it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`uFeatures.ByteFeatures` should be `&uFeatures.ByteFeatures[0]`